# Python why does out of bounds keep changing with every iteration?

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

Every time I run the program it seems to go out of bounds in a different spot and I am not sure why. I am very close to completing this part it has been driving me crazy. Can someone run it on their machine and let me know what they think? I've attempted to control the bounds with different if statements but it turns into a cluster of nonsense after a while.

```
import os.path
import random
import math
import sys
import os
import re



pd = [ #This is the visual of the pyramid

[                 1                    ], #[0][0]  row and total col# ex [2][1] = 5
[              2,    3                 ], #[1][1]
[            4,   5,    6,             ], #[2][2]
[         7,   8,    9,   10,          ], #[3][3]
[      11,  12,   13,  14,   15,       ], #[4][4]
[    16,  17,   18,  19,  20,    21,   ], #[5][5]

]

#The list used to store visited nodes
dots_list = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21]]



#Do not remove this sentence

TOTAL_NUMBERS = 21 # the total numbers in the pyramid
x = 0          # represents left and right direction in pd -- adding goes right, subtracting goes left
y = 0          # represents up and down direction in pd -- adding goes down, subtracting goes up
lower_bound = 1 # used as lower bound in dice selection
upper_bound = 4 # used as upper bound in dice selection
move_counter = 0 # used to count the total number of moves made in game

print("Starting position: ",pd[y][x])  # The starting position used for debugging
start_position = pd[y][x] # The starting point of the game [y][x] up/down y, left/right x set at 1, the top of pyramid
dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.') # Adds dot to number one to indicate start of game
move_counter  += 1 #this counts as a move

# ----  loop begin ----
print('begin loop')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
while any(len(m) < 2 for m in dots_list):

    random_roll = random.randint(upper_bound-2, upper_bound) # Randomly selects a number from 1 to 4 to be used as fair die roll
   # debugging output removing will cause errors
    if random_roll == 1:
        print("Upper left Roll: " ,random_roll)
        print('X is:', x)
        print('Y is:', y)
        print()

        if pd[y][x] == 1 or pd[y][x] == 2 or pd[y][x] == 4 or pd[y][x] == 7 or pd[y][x] == 11 or pd[y][x] == 16:
            # print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased')
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
            print()
            move_counter += 1
        else:
            if y > 0:
                new_pos = pd[y - 1][x - 1]
                y -= 1
                x -= 1
                # print('x: ', x, 'y:', y)
                # print('upper left new pos: ' , new_pos)
                # print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
                start_position = pd[y - 1][x - 1]
                # print('st pos', start_position)


            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
            print('Rolling again')



    elif random_roll == 2:
        print("Upper right Roll: ", random_roll)
        print('X is:', x)
        print('Y is:', y)
        print('moving the next element before changes')
        print()

        if y > 5:
            y-=1
        if x > 5:
            x-=1
        if y > 3:
            y-=1

        if y > x:
            new_pos = pd[y][x]
            start_position = new_pos
            print('new start_pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
        print('X is:', x)
        print('Y is:', y)
        print("after changes")

        start_position = new_pos
        print('new start_pos', start_position)
        dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
        for i in range(len(dots_list)):
            for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
            print()

        print()

        if y <= 5 and y > -1 and x > -1 and x <= 5 and x < y:
            if pd[y][x] == 3 or pd[y][x] == 6 or pd[y][x] == 10 or pd[y][x] == 15 or pd[y][x] == 21:
                new_pos = pd[y][x]
                start_position = new_pos
                # start_position = pd[y][x]
                print(' new start_pos', start_position)
                dots_list[(pd[y][x]) - 1].append('.')
                for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                    for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                        print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                    print()
                move_counter += 1
                print('Rolling again')
                print()

        else:
            if y > -1 and y < 5:

                print('X is:', x)
                print('Y is:', y)
                print()
                print('moving the next element ')

                y -= 1

                print('X is:', x)
                print('Y is:', y)
                print()
                new_pos = pd[y][x]
                #print('upper right new pos: ', new_pos)
               # print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
                start_position = new_pos
                print(' new start_pos', start_position)
                dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
                for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                    for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                        print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                    print()
                move_counter += 1


        print('Rolling again')
        print()


    elif random_roll == 3:
        print("Lower left Roll: ", random_roll)
        print('X is:', x)
        print('Y is:', y)

        print('moving the next element ')
        print()

        if y <= 5 and y > -1 and x > -1 and x <= 5:

            if y != 5:
                y += 1
            print('X is:', x)
            print('Y is:', y)
            new_pos = pd[y][x]
            start_position = new_pos
            print('new start_pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
        elif y > 5:
            print('start pos' ,start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
            y-=1
        elif x > 5:
            print('start pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
            x-=1

        else:
            x-=1
            y-=1



        # if pd[y][x] == 17 :
        #   break;

    else:
        print("Lower right Roll: ", random_roll)
        # print('Invalid Direction --  Move Count Increased:: rr: ' , random_roll)
        print('X is:', x)
        print('Y is:', y)

        print('moving the next element ')
        print()
        x += 1
        y += 1

        print('X is:', x)
        print('Y is:', y)
        print()

        if y <= 5 and y > -1 and x > -1 and x <= 5:
            new_pos = pd[y][x]
            start_position = new_pos
            # start_position = pd[y][x]
            print(' new start_pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
            print('Rolling again')
            print()
        elif y > 5:
            print('start pos' ,start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
            y-=1
            print('Rolling again')
        elif x > 5:
            print('start pos', start_position)
            dots_list[start_position - 1].append('.')
            for i in range(len(dots_list)):
                for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
                    print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
                print()
            move_counter += 1
            x-=1
            print('Rolling again')
            print()
        else:
            x-=1
            y-=1
            print('Rolling again')
            print()








print('outside loop')

# ---- loop end ----

# ---- Results printing ----

print('Move_counter:' ,move_counter)
avg_dots = move_counter/TOTAL_NUMBERS
print('Average number of dots', avg_dots)
for i in range(len(dots_list)):
    for j in range(len(dots_list[i])):
        print(dots_list[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/pyramid.py", line 199, in <module>
    new_pos = pd[y][x]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Start by trimming all unnecessary code (like the game description; who cares?) and pasting the complete error message.

Comment: How do I re-paste?

Comment: Just edit your question.

Comment: Your code is _very_ badly structured. Having one huge `if` in a `while` loop makes it virtually impossible to debug. Someone on SO may be stubborn enough to locate this particular error, but I would say, rewrite your code. At least move all `if` branches into functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the source of your error, but I did notice in the line

```
random_roll = random.randint(upper_bound-2, upper_bound)  # Randomly selects a number from 1 to 4 to be used as fair die roll
```

With `upper_bound = 4` this will be `random.randint(2, 4)`, not `(1, 4)` like it seems you wanted.

However I also agree with DYZ's comment that you should split your program up into functions as opposed to having it all in a single loop with many `if` statements .

Comment: Well, I was thinking that having the loop set up in that fashion would ensure that once the last number received a dot the program would finish. I currently don't understand why putting the ifs into functions would help. Please explain.

Comment: Mainly it is the concept of DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. You have a lot of code here that can be abstracted into more general functions, which will improve the readability of your code significantly, helping you fix bugs down the road as well.